# JMeter tests from v. 5.1.1 do not work on v. 5.6.2

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have tests for JMeter which were written using JMeter 5.1.1. I then installed a newer version of JMeter (5.6.2) on a different machine and tried to run the same tests but they all fail with a 500 error after getting a permission token.
The tests are being run from the GUI and using Windows.

Is there anything different between 5.1.1 and 5.6.2 in terms of how the tests are written?

This is the error for the first 500:
`({"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.6.1","title":"An error occurred while processing your request.","status":500,"traceId":"00-767e601a48ee363a56f169d2665963b4-eb19260c3d9cfd61-00"})`

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

I installed a new version of Jmeter on our test computer as well and the same problem occurs. This was noted when installing JMeter on a new computer.

Also I tried making some changes to the tests but was not successful, there's still the 500 errors.

My expectation was that the tests would work on all versions of JMeter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "my expectation" is wrong, if you look into [JMeter Changelog](https://jmeter.apache.org/changes_history.html) you will find an "Incompatible changes" section for almost each and every release. So you need to go through all the changes from 5.1.1 to 5.6.2 and see if the "Incompatible changes" are impacting the test elements your test is using.

It's also worth trying installing JMeter 5.1.1 from [JMeter archives](https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/) and see if your test works there as it might be the case it's not connected with JMeter version and your tests are broken somehow else and fail i.e. due to missing or improperly implemented [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/correlation-in-jmeter)

Comment: I was way off. The problem has to do with ASPNETCore. Finally checked system logs and noted this. Also noted that this problem only occurs on the newer versions of JMeter and NOT older versions.

Answer (score 0):

I was way off. The problem has to do with ASPNETCore. Finally checked system logs and noted this. Also noted that this problem only occurs on the newer versions of JMeter and NOT older versions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).